# Привязка UI к свойству внутри класса не реализовывающего INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть класс с реализацией кастомного листа. Так же есть свойство Count к которому нужно привязать textblock для отображения значений.

```
public class CustomList : List<T> 
{
   public int Count => { //Logic to get current Count of collection }

   //Реализация коллекции
}
```

Проблема в том, что эта коллекция не реализует INotifyPropertyChanged (и не очень хочется, что бы он был реализован в этом классе) из-за чего обновление свойства никак не отражается в UI. Каким образом решить данную задачу наиболее эффективно? Сделать во вьюмодели таймер или что-то ещё, подскажите! Спасибо!

Comment: выкинуть этот класс и юзать `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: @tym32167 я не могу его выкинуть, это кастомный лист, в котором реализован нужный способ выдачи элементов из него

Comment: унаследоваться от этого листа и прикрутить inotifypropertychanged

Comment: Ну или наследоваться от `ObservableCollection`, а не от `List`

Answer (score -1):

Пример конечно не очень хороший, но вот такой

```
<TextBox>
        <TextBox.Text>
          <Binding Source="{Binding bindingSours", Path="PathName",
                   UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged}"/>
        </TextBox.Text>
      </TextBox>
```

если пример не помог, то вот ссылка https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/11.php

Comment: Это ответ на какой вопрос?

Comment: в смысле на какой? интересно девки пляшут ))))

Comment: Прочитайте еще раз в вопросе *Проблема в том, что ...*, в вашем сообщении решения проблемы нет